# Error installing package in scratch org: "Missing Organization Feature: ContactsToMultipleAccounts"

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, package

I'm using sfdx to create a scratch org, using org shape. First I create an org shape:

```
sfdx force:org:shape:create -u PRODUCTION
```

Then I create a scratch org with the following json:

```
{
    "orgName": "ScratchOrgAlias",
    "features": [
        "Communities",
        "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
        "PersonAccounts",
        "AddCustomObjects:30",
        "MaxCustomLabels:5",
        "PlatformEncryption",
        "PlatformConnect:1",
        "StateAndCountryPicklist"
    ],
    "sourceOrg": "..."
}
```

Note that `ContactsToMultipleAccounts` is in this list.

I create a scratch org with:

```
sfdx force:org:create -v PRODUCTION -f org-definition-from-above.json --durationdays 1 -a ScratchOrgAlias
```

Then I try to install a package:

```
sfdx force:package:install -u ScratchOrgAlias --package MY_PACKAGE_ID -w 99 --noprompt
```

Which errors with:

```
Waiting for the package install request to complete. Status = IN_PROGRESS
ERROR:  Encountered errors installing the package!,Installation errors: 
1) Missing Organization Feature: ContactsToMultipleAccounts
ERROR running force:package:install:  Installation errors: 
1) Missing Organization Feature: ContactsToMultipleAccounts
```

(`sfdx` does notoriously poor error handling, and seems to duplicate the message, and also doesn't seem to return a non-zero exit code, yikes)

I'm confused as to why `ContactsToMultipleAccounts` isn't being respected from my scratch org definition file. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a multi-month outage with scratch orgs that Salesforce refuses to address: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1537#issuecomment-1160737886

Note this is one of several multi-month scratch org outages: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1690

This issue happens non-deterministically when creating a scratch org. The only workaround is to keep retrying. Scratch Orgs are a notoriously poor feature, and Salesforce has notoriously poor infrastructure and accountability for fixing issues like these.